# change module path in Python

Tags: python

I have a project like that :

```
foo/
    | main.py
    | bar/
    | | __init__.py
    | | module1.py
    | | module2.py
```

And I import module1.py in main.py by `import bar.module1`.
But I need rewrite bar's function and keep old code. So I change project like that:

```
foo/
| main.py
| bar/
| | __init__.py
| | oldbar/
| | | module1.py
| | | module2.py
| | | __init__.py
| | newbar/
| | | module1.py
| | | module2.py
| | | __init__.py
```

Now, I do not want to change main.py, and I still use `import bar.module1` in main.py.
Can I do it? add some code into `bar/__init__.py`?

Comment: Do You mean `from subbar import module1`? (Be careful mind a cyclic import)

Comment: oleg, I change my question, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In `foo/bar/__init__.py` you can write:

```
from subbar import module1
from subbar import module2
```

this should allow you to use `import bar.module1` from `main.py`

Comment: works for me... tested with your updated version https://gist.github.com/rxdazn/5780497 (just updated gist a few seconds ago, reload it)

Comment: Yes. if I use `from bar import module1`, it works. But, if I use `import bar.module1`, it does not work

Comment: importing will execute `__init__.py` files in sub folders (see [http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages](Python - The import system: regular packages). This means `bar/__ini__.py` will be executed once `bar` is imported. By using `import bar.module1`, `bar/__init__.py` is not loaded so it does not know `bar/newbar/module1` exists. Either use `from bar import module1` with `module1.hello()` or `import bar` with `bar.module1.hello()`

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there any method to do it except adding code in `__init__.py` file?